# only rebuild when necessary even though we depend on a subproject with its own Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

#### Situation

I have a Makefile that depends on a few things from a subproject that has its own Makefile.  In the subproject, the targets have dependencies which I was hoping my main project would not have to know about.  So I am trying to use the subproject's Makefile to build anything I need from it when necessary.  This is what I have in my sample project before building:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs head
==> ./subproject/Makefile <==
binary: source.txt
        echo subproject source: > $@
        date >> $@
        cat $< >> $@
clean:
        rm binary

==> ./subproject/source.txt <==
this is the subproject source code

==> ./Makefile <==
binary: source.txt subproject/binary
        echo main source: > $@
        date >> $@
        cat $^ >> $@
subproject/%:
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)
clean:
        rm binary
        $(MAKE) -C subproject clean


==> ./source.txt <==
this is the main source code
```

and this is what I have after building:

```
$ make
make -C subproject binary
make[1]: Entering directory '~/make-example/subproject'
echo subproject source: > binary
date >> binary
cat source.txt >> binary
make[1]: Leaving directory '~/make-example/subproject'
echo main source: > binary
date >> binary
cat source.txt subproject/binary >> binary
$ find . -type f | xargs head
==> ./subproject/Makefile <==
binary: source.txt
        echo subproject source: > $@
        date >> $@
        cat $< >> $@
clean:
        rm binary

==> ./subproject/binary <==
subproject source:
Di 10. Okt 14:01:03 CEST 2023
this is the subproject source code

==> ./subproject/source.txt <==
this is the subproject source code

==> ./Makefile <==
binary: source.txt subproject/binary
        echo main source: > $@
        date >> $@
        cat $^ >> $@
subproject/%:
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)
clean:
        rm binary
        $(MAKE) -C subproject clean


==> ./binary <==
main source:
Di 10. Okt 14:01:03 CEST 2023
this is the main source code
subproject source:
Di 10. Okt 14:01:03 CEST 2023
this is the subproject source code

==> ./source.txt <==
this is the main source code
alex@elephant:~/make-example$
```

#### Problem

When I change `subproject/source.txt`, and run `make` in the parent project, it still doesn't recompile.

I can almost fix that like this:

```
subproject/%: always
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)
always:
```

when make is run in the subproject, `subproject/binary` will not be recompiled.  However, `binary` in the parent project will still get recompiled because one of its prereqs got run, even if the date on prereq file is old.

---

#### Question

So I think that the answer is probably that this is not how I am supposed to be doing it.
I really wanted the parent project and subproject to know as little about one another as possible.

Is there any way to make the parent project check the date on `subproject/binary` and use that to determine whether to rebuild `binary` even if the `subproject/binary` formula was run?

I would like to be able to type `make` and build it, and then change `subproject/source.txt` and type `make` again in the main project, and have it recompile `subproject/binary` and then recompile `binary` as a result, and then right after, not change anything, and type `make` again, not recompile anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> However, binary in the parent project will still get recompiled because one of its prereqs got run, even if the date on prereq file is old.

That is not how make works.  Just because a recipe is invoked does not mean that make always assumes that the target was modified; make will examine the modification time of the prerequisite and compare it, even if the prerequisite's recipe was invoked.

So, if you're seeing `binary` always rebuilt then something else is happening here: maybe the sub-make is written in such a way that it always modifies the binary.  You may want to use `make --trace` or `make -d` to understand why make decides to rebuild `binary`.

Example:

```
UPDATE = touch $@
binary: prereq; touch $@
prereq: FORCE ; : updating; $(UPDATE)
FORCE:
```

Now:

```
$ make
: updating; touch prereq
touch binary

$ make
: updating; touch prereq
touch binary
```

as expected, but now if we don't actually change the prerequisite:

```
$ make UPDATE=
: updating;
```

We can see that the prerequisite updating rule was run, but since it didn't actually change `prereq`, make didn't rebuild `binary`.

Comment: I don't know what to say! I was totally mistaken when I thought my minimal example had the same issue as my actual project. I am tempted to nominate this question for deletion if that OK with you

Comment: I mean your answer is valuable - but the question makes sense - so maybe it's ok to leave it